# How to create an interface based on another interface but only the type used as an input for a generic class?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following interface for my Angular reactive form

```
export interface LoginForm {
    username: FormControl<string>,
    password: FormConrtol<string>
}
```

now I want to create an interface with the value of the form

```
export interface LoginFormValue {
    username: string,
    password: string
}
```

but I have forms with a lot of attributes so I don't want to manually type the type of the value of the form. How would do it in an automatic way?

Comment: You should look into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to generate `LoginForm` from `LoginFormValue`.

Answer (score 0):

This is redundant.

In Angular 14, just keep the value interface, you don't need a type for your form.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-usvbaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  form = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // Look at the type of the "value" variable
    const value = this.form.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I got an error in your Stackblitz example => Type '(string | ((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors)[])[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: @Invader updated blitz & answer